Почему хедер не липнет к верхней части браузера
Всем привет!
Подскажите почему так хедер не полностью не липнет к верхней части браузера
в цсс нормалайз включен тестил и без него пищет что 8пл есть
спасибо за ранее

Разметка и стили должны быть в вопросе текстом. Картинка как визуализация результата

Это явно не 8...

Выкладите код текстом.

Так работает margin collapse. Максимум из 8px body и 1em p - 1em.

нужно сделать сброс стилей. по умолчанию каждый браузер имеет свои стилевые правила. можно добавить вначале стилевого файла для всех элементов
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
или
https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/
